# Can't edit text on Google Web Designer after I've played with keyframes

Tags: google-web-designer

Normally I can select the layer I want then select the text tool and edit it but for some reason, after putting in some key frames so the texts fades in and out I can't seem to select the text to edit.

I've locked all the other layers so only the text layer I want to edit is editable but I can't change it. All I can do is move it about.

Answer (score 3):

I know this question is old but for future searchers - I think this is a bug so I don't have a "solution", but a workaround. 
To make a change to your text:

1. Switch to 'Code View',
2. Search (ctrl + F) for your text
3. Change your text
4. Switch back to design view

This is a hack, but its the best option - especially if you've already invested lots of time into this and now find yourself stuck.

Answer (score 2):

Okay, I figured out the actual bug causing this and have a solution that is less of a hack. The reason you can't select text is because there are visible layers above your text layer blocking your click. You would assume that if those visible layers are locked, you can click through but that isn't how Google Web Designer works (right now). 
So, make all layers invisible, then make just your text layer visible and then you can click to edit it.

Answer (score 0):

I have encounter this problem when editing a template. I could only edit the text of first layer... In order to edit the second layer text and so on you must hide the fist layer.

Answer (score 0):

I have just found out there is another way: Try to copy all layers to a new document with the same preferences. sometimes it`s rather easier than change the code